# Import Error on Stackblitz when trying to add component to module file

Tags: html, css, angularjs, stackblitz

I'm using Stackblitz to practice angularJS and it's coming up with an error when I attempt to import a component in the app.module.ts file.

```
Import error, can't find file:
./heroes/heroes.component
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akxx4e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update below Changes, because it's in different folder

```
import { HeroesComponent } from '../heroes/heroes.component';
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

This issue occurs due to component creation inside wrong location. 
 So `heroes component` should be created inside `app` root. **This is the recommended answer.**

---

### Method 2

Correcting component's relative path is also works. **But it is not the correct answer.**

```
import { HeroesComponent } from '../heroes/heroes.component';
```

Comment: Method 2 is the answer most suited to what I need as I should be able to import files from other directories I would think, and not be limited to putting all files in the same directory. I was aware of Method 1 as a solution but it's not what I wanted to do.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)